# Create a new Powershell function

Tags: azure, powershell

Create a new Azure function App - Powershell function?

Cannot locate language set or Powershell template as discussed in blog article
https://codehollow.com/2016/11/working-azure-functions-part-1-powershell/

Choose a template below or go to the quickstart
Language PowerShell Scenario Experimental

HttpTrigger-PowerShell (Template I'm seeking)
A PowerShell function that will be run whenever it receives an HTTP request.

See OneDrive Image

[image]

Azure Function App clicked the plus sign - Azure Functions for .NET - getting started I tried Webhook+API plus In portal neither allow me to set the language or set to PowerShell.

```
#Post method: $req
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw ! ConvertFrom-Json
$name = $requestBody.name

#Get method: each query string parameter is it own variable'

If ($req_query_name)
{
   $name = $req-query_name
}

out-file -Encoding Ascii -filePath $res -inputobject "Hello $name"
```

I would expect to see the above code run.ps1.

Comment: Whats the issue ?

Comment: "I tried Webhook+API plus" - why not try one of the options in your screenshot if you want a PowerShell function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blog you refered is too old. Now on Azure portal, to create an instance of Azure Functions, you will see two types as the figures below.

Fig 1. Azure Functions on Windows to support .NET, JavaScript, Java languages

[image]

Fig 2. Azure Functions on Linux to support .NET, JavaScript, Python languages

[image]

So there is not PowerShell language supported directly. But you can create a Windows instance for .NET, then to create a new function with feature `Experimental Language Support` enabled as below, you will see the options for PowerShell.

[image]

Next, for example, to click the `PowerShell` link of `HTTP trigger` to create a new PowerShell function.

[image]

Then, you can edit, develop, test and run it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you really appreciated you taking the time to answer.

Comment: Thank you, this helped Peter